# Is "for winter" wrong and why?

Tags: word-usage

From my kid's textbook:

My favorite activity ___ winter is ice-skating.

The choices include "for", "during", "in" among others. I know that "in" is the right answer (which it is) but I couldn't tell why "for" isn't. It seems more natural to say "for the winter" or "for winters", similar to "during", which seems to imply it should be followed by a "concrete" noun, not an "abstract" noun, but then there are usages like "for freedom" and "for home use", etc.

Is "for winter" grammatically wrong, or is it just idiomatic rules?

Comment: The grammar is fine, but it's wrong *semantically*. Can you think of a context where "for" has the same meaning as intended here? "For freedom" doesn't work because that means, "towards the goal of freedom". "For home use" indicates the purpose. Neither of those fit with "in winter".

Comment: "My favourite winter activity is ...."

Comment: "for" suggests that winter is a special occasion for which one chooses a principal activity. Like choosing an activity for your birthday or a song for your wedding.